# Play framework 2 java view - Header, body, footer style page building using Promise

Tags: html, view, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I would like to build final page in typical header-body-footer pattern where header, body and footer each coming from different sources. Header and body would typically come from content management system and body lets say would come from REST service.

I would need to make WS call for each of these preferably in asynchronous manner.

How can I write a play controller action which essentially wraps three Promises for each of these call?

Answer (score 1):

First, start the three WS calls. They will run in parallel.

```java
Promise<WS.Response> header = WS.url("http://source1.com/header").get();
Promise<WS.Response> body   = WS.url("http://source2.com/body").get();
Promise<WS.Response> footer = WS.url("http://source3.com/footer").get();
```

Next make a Promise that combines all three Responses. By using this combined Promise we will be wait for all three Responses to complete before we start producing a Result.

```java
Promise<List<WS.Response>> headerBodyFooter = Promise.sequence(
  Arrays.asList(new Promise<WS.Response>[] {
    header, body, footer
  })
);
```

Wait on that the Promise of the three Responses. Once we have three responses we can produce a Result.

```java
Promise<Result> result = headerBodyFooter.map(new Function<List<WS.Response>,Result>() {
  public Result apply(List<WS.Response> responses) {
    WS.Response header = responses.get(0);
    WS.Response body   = responses.get(1);
    WS.Response footer = responses.get(2);
    ...
    ... use header, body and footer to produce a result ...
    ...
    return result;
  }
});
```

Then return the Promise of a Result we just created from your action.

```java
return result;
```

Comment: Thank you! I did exactly this way and it is working. Only teak I needed to do was to identify which one is header response, footer and the body as they are three async calls and ordering is not guaranteed

Comment: I don't understand. Promise.sequence() will always return you a sequence in the order header/body/footer, irrespective of the order that the underlying async calls actually complete.

Comment: Yes, on careful inspection I realize sequence does preserve order. Sorry about misunderstanding